# Changing MX records in named zone file

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dns-zone, dns-hosting

I forgot how all this works.  I have a GoDaddy account, using my own DNS and whatnot.  I'm having trouble getting my email to work.  They said I need to update my MX records.  basically, I have the following.  184.168.30.42 is the domain's IP address, obviously.

```
gamengai.com.   14400   IN      NS      n1
gamengai.com.   14400   IN      NS      n2
ns1             14400   IN      A       184.168.30.42
ns2             14400   IN      A       184.168.30.42
gamengai.com.   14400   IN      A       184.168.30.42
localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1
ftp             14400   IN      A       184.168.30.42
www             14400   IN      A       184.168.30.42
mail            14400   IN      A       184.168.30.42
subdomain       14400   IN      A       184.168.30.42
gamengai.com    14400   IN      MX      10      mail
```

Mail doesn't work though... they say to make the following change:

```
0   smtp.secureserver.net
10  mailstore1.secureserver.net
```

So should the last line point to mailstore1.secureserver.net instead of mail in the last field?  What about the other line?

I had this working at one time, but it's totally gotten away from me.  It's a virtual dedicated server and their support for this stuff is pretty bad... almost as bad as my admin skills since I went the programmer route.

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem is missing trailing dot in your MX records.**

Domain names in your zone file which don't end with a dot, considered relative to the zone domain. This is how you have defined `ftp.gamengai.com`, `www.gamengai.com` etc.

Currently your zone have no MX records for `gamengai.com`, instead it have MX records for `gamengai.com.gamengai.com`

```
dig gamengai.com.gamengai.com MX +short
10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.gamengai.com.
0 smtp.secureserver.net.gamengai.com.
```

Aparently, now trailing dot is missing in both - label and target hostname of the MX record.

Answer (score 0):

You can define more than one mail server for the domain to handle mails. so the lowest number has the highest priority and is the one which a mail server tries to contact first. If that fails, it tries the next one and so on.

so your config should look like:

```
gamengai.com.    14400   IN      MX      0      smtp.secureserver.net.
gamengai.com.    14400   IN      MX      10     mailstore1.secureserver.net.
```

If you use a FQDN hostname (instead of an IP) make sure to add the trailing dot at the end of your entry in order to guarantee a proper lookup.

You can check your settings for example with the host commando from a Linux shell
   `host -t MX gamengai.com`

Comment: Thanks -- I have made the edit.  I don't have 'host' installed on the box, and I'm afraid I know nothing of yum.  I have installed net-dns/host on my Gentoo box at home.  It moans that there is no MX record present at that domain.  I assume I need to wait for propagation?

Comment: Thanks -- I missed the dots thing.  Changed, restarted named.  My remote machine is still moaning about it not having an MX record though.

Comment: is it still now working? The trailing dots were also explained in my first answer. Your setup looks correct to me now. Heres the result of host -t MX gamengai.com
gamengai.com mail is handled by 0 smtp.secureserver.net.
gamengai.com mail is handled by 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.

Comment: It does!  Thanks -- I actually got a mail now.  Now to just change the email address that has this one registered to at that bank and never deal with it again. :)

Cheers!

Comment: This is not working actually there should be tailing `.` after domain